# Complex Logic to update a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

My table looks like the following

```
Regno      Date       Year Batch h1   h2   h3  h4    h5   Att
1138M0345  25-07-2013  3    1    P    P    P  NULL  NULL  NULL
1138M0346  25-07-2013  3    1    P    P    P  NULL  NULL  NULL
1138M0347  25-07-2013  3    1    P    P    P  NULL  NULL  NULL
1138M0348  25-07-2013  3    1    P    P    P  NULL  NULL  NULL
1138M0349  25-07-2013  3    1    P    P    P  NULL  NULL  NULL
1138M0350  25-07-2013  3    1    P    P    P  NULL  NULL  NULL
1138M0351  25-07-2013  3    1    P    P    P  NULL  NULL  NULL
1138M0352  25-07-2013  3    1    P    P    P  NULL  NULL  NULL
1138M0353  25-07-2013  3    1    P    P    P  NULL  NULL  NULL
1138M0343  25-07-2013  3    1    A    A    A  NULL  NULL  NULL
1138M0344  25-07-2013  3    1    A    A    A  NULL  NULL  NULL
```

The fields **h1, h2,h3,h4,h5, and att can store null values**
att field is to store a student's attendance for the day. I need to update field **att** with **P/A/1/2** under following conditions

```
1. 'P' if H1 through H5 contains 'P' (Meaning present for the whole day)
2. '1' if H1 through H3 contains 'P' (Meaning present for the first session)
3. '2' if H4 and H5 contains 'P' (Meaning present for the second session)
4. NULL if any of H1 through H5 contains NULL (Meaning table needs to be updated completely)
5. Else 'A' (Meaning absent for the whole day)
```

Can anyone help me with the logic

Comment: Where is the field **`app`**?

Comment: Use a CASE statement? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry the field is Att

Comment: @astander I added an answer on how I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that will update the table for specified date range

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
DECLARE @EndDate datetime

SET @StartDate = '07/01/2013'
SET @EndDate = '07/26/2013'

UPDATE StudentAttendance
SET Att = 
 (
    CASE
       WHEN (H1 is null) or (H2 is null) or (H3 is null) (H4 is null) (H5 is null) THEN NULL
       WHEN H1='P' and H2='P' and H3='P' and H4='P' and H5='P' THEN 'P'
       WHEN H1='P' and H2='P' and H3='P' THEN 'P'
       WHEN H4='P' and H5='P' THEN 'P'
       ELSE 'A' 
    END
)
WHERE Date BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Comment: Following query did the trick  `UPDATE student_attendance_table SET att = 
CASE 
WHEN (h1 IS NULL) or (h2 IS NULL) or (h3 IS NULL) or (h4 IS NULL) or (h5 IS NULL) THEN NULL 
WHEN h1='P' and h2='P' and h3='P' and h4='P' and h5='P' THEN 'P' 
WHEN h1='P' and h2='P' and h3='P' THEN '1' 
WHEN h4='P' and h5='P' THEN '2' 
ELSE 'A' 
END 
WHERE regno='" & reg & "' AND date='" & dtp1.Text & "' AND year=" & year & " AND batch= " & batch &"`

Comment: @Dineshbabu - Please don't put code in a comment.  Update your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an SQL query also

```
select [Regno], [Date], [Year], [Batch] as KEY,
case 
when 
(ISNULL(H1,'')='' OR ISNULL(H2,'')='' 
OR ISNULL(H3,'')='' OR ISNULL(H4,'')='' 
OR ISNULL(H5,'')='') THEN NULL
when (H1='P' and H2='P' and H3='P' and H4='P' and H5='P') THEN 'P'
when (H1='P' and H2='P' and H3='P') THEN 'P'
when (H4='P' and H5='P') THEN 'P'
ELSE 'A' END as APP
from Table1
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cdb7e5/7)**

Comment: I need to fetch the rows with DATE,REGNO,YEAR and BATCH as key

Answer (score 0):

if i were to fetch a value and insert into a table first i would write the logic to find the value for a particular student (whether p,a,1/2..)then i would start the sql part to update the found value in the sql query....

say to update att for 1138M0345

- i would fetch that record using `select ... where` regNo = '1138M0345' and Date ='ur date'
- check the possibilities for P, A, 1 and 2 in `condition` statement
- store result from previous step, and close the query
- open another query(mostly update statement with where regNo = `1138M0345` ), and update 'att'

Comment: opening sql query, what i mean update,insert or delete some record and close the connection.. so what record i need to manipulate i do it first then start doing it in sql...

Comment: May I request you for a detailed logic

Comment: from where do you know a student is p,a,1 or 2 is it from the vb form

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Hinata thanx for reminding a point from the rule book....if the author is commenting at an answer i see more accessible to reply at the place where he is seen last...(finding ur lost valet, where u have seen it last..)...thanx again... ;)

Comment: @x-code to find out p,a,1,2 is the question. I don't know how to compare the fields and come to a decision

Comment: I have stored the regno,year,batch is lists date from the control I need to find the rows with given regno,year, batch and date and update the att field with p/a/1/2 according to the condition mentioned in my question. How to update the table accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

The query that worked is

```
UPDATE student_attendance_table SET att = 
  CASE 
    WHEN (h1 IS NULL) or (h2 IS NULL) or (h3 IS NULL) or (h4 IS NULL) or (h5 IS NULL) THEN NULL 
    WHEN h1='P' and h2='P' and h3='P' and h4='P' and h5='P' THEN 'P' 
    WHEN h1='P' and h2='P' and h3='P' THEN '1' 
    WHEN h4='P' and h5='P' THEN '2' 
    ELSE 'A' 
  END 
WHERE regno='" & reg & "' AND date='" & dtp1.Text & "' AND year=" & year & " AND batch= " & batch &"
```